The TCP connection is always reset while transmitting a 6M file
I have a web server, which allows user to upload or download files through HTTP requests.
         Internet                     Internet                               loopback interface           LAN
client ------------> secure gateway ------------> secure gateway component ---------------------> Envoy -------> web server

As you see, secure gateway component and Envoy are deployed on a same backend server machine, they use lo (127.0.0.1) to communicate with each other.
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 149217825  bytes 615211974025 (572.9 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 149217825  bytes 615211974025 (572.9 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

I just got a very weird problem.
When client sends a HTTP request with the header Connection: close to download a 6M file, the TCP connection is always reset so that the client can't receive the response with the file correctly. I've tried 1M file, 2M file, 12M file, 100M file, the client can receive all of them correctly. Only 6M file could trigger the rst error.

As you see, 1443 is the server and 56948 is the client. The size of the file is more than 6000000, but the server sends a rst packet on 5619253, which is less than the size of the file.
In terms of HTTP, a request with Connection: close header means that the server should send immediately FIN packet while it finished sending data. If I make the client send HTTP request with Connection: keep-alive, which makes the server keep the TCP connection alive, this 6M-file issue would be gone.
Besides, I executed cat /proc/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem and here is the output:
4096    87380   6291456

The maximum memory size is 6291456, which exactly equals to 6M.
In a word, for now I have three clues:

the 6M issue happens between two processes on the same machine, using lo to communicate;
tcp_rmem - 6291456, which exactly equals to 6M;
Connection: keep-alive makes the issue disappear.

Could someone tell me why the connection is unexpectedly reset on 6M file?

the server sends a rst packet what tests did you perform to confirm that the web server is the source of the RST?

@GregAskew Well, I only have the output of tcpdump. It told me that 1443 -> 56948 generated the SRT. And 1443 is the server. That's all I know. I'm not an expert on network. So maybe I misunderstood the output of tcpdump.

@GregAskew So maybe it's the kernel who generates the RST? Envoy wrote the complete data into socket buffer and the secure gateway component haven't read it and the kernel generated a RST packet for some reason?

You haven't confirmed the source of the RST. When you perform a capture, it's usually necessary to capture at multiple points. Such as both ends. Currently you only know that the client endpoint is not sending it. It could be any point in the connection.

@GregAskew  In my case, the client and the server are deployed on the same machine. I only know that I can capture the network interface that the client and the server used with the tool tcpdump. What do you mean by "at multiple points"?

Who created such an inferior design that you are unable to determine which component is failing?

A TCP connection reset during the transmission of a 6M file could be due to several issues. Common causes include network congestion leading to packet loss, timeouts, or interference from security mechanisms like firewalls or intrusion detection systems. It might also be due to a misconfigured TCP window size or other parameters on either the sender or receiver. Investigate network logs and configurations on both ends to identify the exact cause. Ensure that both ends are properly configured and that the network path is stable and not congested.
